# How to Left Justify the Lettrine Only with the Text After Inserting Opening Quotation Marks

Tags: luatex, automation, lettrine, quotation, justification

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine,xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\input GoudyIn.fd
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}

\fboxsep=0pt % padding thickness
\fboxrule=0pt % border thickness

\def\openingquotes{\large ``\,}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\large

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.30,findent=.21em,nindent=2.5pt]{\fcolorbox{black}{blue!35}{Y\kern-.04em}}{ou} may delay but time will not.'' \lipsum[13]
\vskip 35pt
\lettrine[lines=3,ante=\openingquotes,loversize=.30,findent=.21em,nindent=2.5pt]{\fcolorbox{black}{blue!35}{Y\kern-.04em}}{ou} may delay but time will not.'' \lipsum[13]
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

After having defined and inserted a pair of opening quotation marks, I would like the lettrine itself (not the quotation marks) be positioned flush-left with the text as it is displayed in the first paragraph. (Hence, the opening quotes will hang to the left of the justification of the text.)

I know that I can use `lhang=`(somewhere perhaps around .12, .13, .14, or so, to approximate by inspection and by trial and error where to position the lettrine; but, I would like to ask if this may be more precisely and automatically accomplished given that there may be several such lettrines in a document with perhaps, different sizes.

So---

QUESTION: How may I automatically (if possible) position a lettrine containing opening quotes so that the lettrine itself is left justified with the rest of the text? I am compiling with `lualatex` if that makes a difference.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just `\llap` the quotation marks...

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine,xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\input GoudyIn.fd
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}

\fboxsep=0pt % padding thickness
\fboxrule=0pt % border thickness

\def\openingquotes{\large ``\,}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\large

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.30,findent=.21em,nindent=2.5pt]{\fcolorbox{black}{blue!35}{Y\kern-.04em}}{ou} may delay but time will not.'' \lipsum[13]
\vskip 35pt
\lettrine[lines=3,ante=\llap{\openingquotes},loversize=.30,findent=.21em,nindent=2.5pt]{\fcolorbox{black}{blue!35}{Y\kern-.04em}}{ou} may delay but time will not.'' \lipsum[13]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I have to wait (again) for the system to let me accept the answer.

Comment: It used to be 10 minutes.  It appears that it's been upped to 15 or thereabouts. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Just hide the width of the quotes ``` \def\openingquotes{\makebox[0pt][r]{\large ``\,}} ```